# Plist To SQLITE

Tags: ios, sqlite, plist, converters

I'm trying to convert my .plist to SQLITE DB since my app got reject because .plist was too big.

I've been trying few days and still don't know how to convert this. First tried to find some converted but couldn't find any so now I'm trying to convert threw code with enumeration but can't get right result.

Could anyone help me convert this to SQLITE (just need SQL INSERT stuff and relations if needed, since I'm going to use FMDB it will be easy to implement in Xcode):

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>State</key>
    <string>Alabama</string>
    <key>Area code</key>
    <dict>
        <key>205</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>City</key>
                <string>Birmingham, AL</string>
                <key>County</key>
                <string>Jefferson</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>City</key>
                <string>Birmingham, AL</string>
                <key>County</key>
                <string>Shelby</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>251</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>City</key>
                <string>Mobile, AL</string>
                <key>County</key>
                <string>Mobile</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>City</key>
                <string>Atmore, AL</string>
                <key>County</key>
                <string>Escambia</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>

    <key>Zip code</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>City</key>
            <string>Wetumpka</string>
            <key>County</key>
            <string>Elmore</string>
            <key>Zip code</key>
            <string>36093</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>City</key>
            <string>Winfield</string>
            <key>County</key>
            <string>Fayette</string>
            <key>Zip code</key>
            <string>35594</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Top array contains dictionary of states (this is just Alabama, all states are included in, but should be enough for example).

Thanks.

Comment: Also To-Core-Data would also be helpful if anyone can help. Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything at all about SQLite?  How did you originally create the XML data?  (As I understand it you want to ship a "canned" SQLite DB, so you probably want to build it on a desktop system.  Might as well start from your original data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to migrate to Core Data.  Add a model to your project, it's under "Core Data" in the file wizard.

Off-hand it looks like you'll want two entities: State and AreaCode; State would have a toMany relationship with the AreaCode entity.  Once these entities are constructed in the model builder you can export them and Xcode will generate the classes for you.

If you want to migrate your current plist directly; I think the best way is to open the plist as a dictionary; for every State dictionary call initWithEntity: and do the appropriate -[setValue: forKey:] for your properties from the dictionary.  Then once you save the object context everything will be persisted for you.